# How to make a simple Boolean condition

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-expression

What am I doing wrong with my code?

I'm trying to get it so when I run *happy_home* it comes out true when there is at least one cat and no dogs.

```
cat_count = 2
dog_count = 0

if cat_count > 0:
    has_cat = True

if dog_count > 0:
    has_dog = False

happy_home = (has_cat and has_dog)

happy_home
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be setting `has_dog` to `True` if `dog_count > 0` ?

Comment: @sj95126 they want the statement to be true if there are 0 dogs.

Comment: "at least 1 cat and no dog" sounds different from `has_cat and has_dog`. Did you mean to write `has_cat and not has_dog` in your code? (and *also* set `has_dog` to `True` if `dog_count > 0`)

Comment: Can you tell more about why you think that you are doing something wrong?

Comment: @BTables: What I mean is, checking for more than zero dogs and setting `has_dog` to `False` doesn't make sense.

Comment: do you mean `happy_home = has_cat and not has_dog`

Comment: @sj95126 Ah, I see. I was just looking at the `True`/`False` values which make sense. The naming...does not.

Answer (score 0):

You really only need this.

```
cat_count = 2
dog_count = 0

print(cat_count > 0 and dog_count == 0)
```

Comment: OP wants it to be true if there are cats and 0 dogs.

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed too fast

Comment: Still, an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What about operator precedence (*and* is usually high, but if it had been *or* it would have been lower)? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71069955/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have has_cat and has_dog attributes with two if statements? You can simply check both of them at the same if statement. Please check out the code at below:

```
#!/bin/python3

cat_count = 2
dog_count = 0

happy_home = False

if cat_count > 0 and dog_count == 0:
    happy_home = True

print(happy_home)
```

Comment: you can directly make `happy_home = cat_count > 0 and dog_count == 0` without the if and without initializing happy_house to false

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just wanted to keep the same structure at the question, since the owner of the question is new to python.

Answer (score 0):

The originally posted code **does not define the has_dog variable**, as shown by the following error message:

```
python

Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> cat_count = 2
    >>> dog_count = 0
    >>>
    >>> if cat_count > 0:
    ...     has_cat = True
    ...
    >>> if dog_count > 0:
    ...     has_dog = False
    ...
    >>> happy_home = (has_cat and has_dog)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'has_dog' is not defined
    >>>
```

Here is the fixed code:

```
cat_count = 2
dog_count = 0

if cat_count > 0:
    has_cat = True
else:
    has_cat = False


if dog_count > 0:
    has_dog = False
else:
    has_dog = True


happy_home = (has_cat and has_dog)

happy_home
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71192881/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).